# Plugins in admin navigation

Tags: plugins, control-panel, admin

Is it possible to choose which plugins appear in the main admin navigation?

I've installed Entry Count (https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-entry-count) and it's now showing in the navigation (under Users).

In this case, I'd prefer to just access Entry Count via Settings > Plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a plugin for that by Josh Crawford
https://github.com/engram-design/CPNav

Answer (score 2):

Nothing built-in, but you could hide it using the Control Panel CSS plugin (https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-cpcss) and set it to display those to not display.

For that plugin your CSS to hide it should be:

```
#nav-entrycount {display:none;}
```